# Looping through object and inputing into certain indexes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, loops

I am looking to loop through an object and input into certain indexes using jQuery. I am using Sweet Alert 2 and the chaining modals but I need to generate the titles dynamically. The titles are in the array below.

The object used by SA2 is the following:

```
var steps = [{
    title: 'Questions', 
    input: 'radio', 
    inputOptions: inputOptions, 
}]
```

I guess 'each' of some kind after the squared bracket.

```
["Washing Machine diagnosis", "Washing Machine type", "Have you ever had an engineer look at this fault?", "Has an engineer looked at this appliance in the last 6 months?", "Has anybody that is not a qualified repair engineer attempted to repair the Washing Machine?", "Duration of problem", "When did you purchase this Washing Machine?", "Do you have a receipt?"]
```

Essentailly I need to create:

```
var steps = [{
    title: 'Washing Machine diagnosis', 
    input: 'radio', 
    inputOptions: inputOptions, 
},
{
    title: 'Washing Machine diagnosis', 
    input: 'radio', 
    inputOptions: inputOptions, 
}]
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

es6

```js
var result = ["Washing Machine diagnosis", "Washing Machine type", "Have you ever had an engineer look at this fault?", "Has an engineer looked at this appliance in the last 6 months?", "Has anybody that is not a qualified repair engineer attempted to repair the Washing Machine?", "Duration of problem", "When did you purchase this Washing Machine?", "Do you have a receipt?"]
             .map(e => ({title:e,input:"radio",inputOptions:{}}));
console.log(result)
```

es5

```js
var result = ["Washing Machine diagnosis", "Washing Machine type", "Have you ever had an engineer look at this fault?", "Has an engineer looked at this appliance in the last 6 months?", "Has anybody that is not a qualified repair engineer attempted to repair the Washing Machine?", "Duration of problem", "When did you purchase this Washing Machine?", "Do you have a receipt?"]
             .map(function(e){
               return {title:e,input:"radio",inputOptions:{}};
               });
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This looks great. Just a quick question on it, I am struggling to understand where the result variable gets passed into the function? @sabithpocker

Comment: map takes your array and applies the function to each element, then returns the transformed array which is stored in `result`. Eg: `x =[1,4,9].map(Math.sqrt)` will make `x` as `[1,2,3]`. Here the function takes `"Washing Machine diagnosis"` and converts it to `{title: "Washing..", input:"radio",....}`. Read the MDN page link in the answer.

Comment: Does it take the closest array because I dont see anything that makes the connection between the two? No variable or in the same function?

Comment: The function gets the array item as parameter, `e` in the example. And inside the function title is set to `e`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a template object:

```
var step = {
    title        : '',
    input        : 'radio',
    inputOptions : inputOptions
};
```

Then you will just iterate through the array:

```
var titles = [
    "Washing Machine diagnosis",
    "Washing Machine type",
    ...
    "Do you have a receipt?"
];

var steps = titles.map((title) => {
    var clone = Object.assign({}, step);
    clone.title = title;
    return clone;
});
```

or just use Underscore.js to clone objects if you do not like `assign()`

Comment: Or just create new object in `map` callback, yes. It may be event easier.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
$.each(steps, function(i, step){
     step.title = myArray[i];
});
```

This uses JQuery to loop through the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i've understand your question but how about this

```
const titles = ["Washing Machine diagnosis", "Washing Machine type", "Have you ever had an engineer look at this fault?", "Has an engineer looked at this appliance in the last 6 months?", "Has anybody that is not a qualified repair engineer attempted to repair the Washing Machine?", "Duration of problem", "When did you purchase this Washing Machine?", "Do you have a receipt?"]

const steps = titles.map((title) => {
  return {
    title,
    input: 'radio',
    inputOptions
  }
})
```